# How do I get my character to move?

Tags: python, pygame

This is my code:

```python
import pygame
import time
import math
from utils import scale_image

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1300, 800
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("MK1")
BG = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("imgs/mk 11 dragon grotto.jpg"),(WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.update()

Raiden = scale_image(pygame.image.load("imgs/Raiden pose.png"),0.4)

run = True
while run:
    WIN.blit(BG, (0,0))
    
    r_x = 150
    r_y = 0
    
    Raiden_start_pos = (r_x,r_y)
    WIN.blit(Raiden,(Raiden_start_pos))
    
    
    pygame.display.update()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        r_y += 5
        WIN.blit(Raiden,(Raiden_start_pos))
        pygame.display.update()
        
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        r_y -= 5
        WIN.blit(Raiden,(Raiden_start_pos))
        pygame.display.update()
    
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            break
```

I'm essentially hoping by pressing the W and S keys the character(Raiden) can move up and down through updating the y coordinate. However, it doesn't seem to be working and nothing changes when I press W or S. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in the scope of `r_x` and `r_y`. You're updating `r_y` inside the `if` block, but then when you call `WIN.blit(Raiden,(Raiden_start_pos))` again, it's still referring to the initial `Raiden_start_pos` tuple you defined before the `if` statements, which are not updated after their initial definition. You should move the `Raiden_start_pos = (r_x, r_y)` line to after you handle the key presses.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to move the following code:
`r_x = 150`
`r_y = 0`
out of the while loop. I recommend putting it after:
`Raiden = scale_image(pygame.image.load("imgs/Raiden pose.png"),0.4)`
So that you can keep your related code closer together.

As your code is now, r_x and r_y are reset back to 150 (r_x) & 0 (r_y) every frame.
You should also be able to remove the `WIN.blit(...)` and `pygame.display.update()` from the keyboard section, because you are already blitting and updating before that.

As it stands (and assuming the change in code doesn't cause bugs), the `.blit` and`.update()` in the keyboard section does a second blit and second update of the window. It may look like some weird effect is being applied to Raiden's sprite, as you aren't 'clearing' the screen between the blitting of Raiden's sprite.

I think the blitting of the background image 'clears' the screen in your current iteration, but to make sure that you don't have an issue in the future related to clearing the screen, add `WIN.screen.fill((color_of_your_choosing))` to the beginning of your while loop, where `color_of_your_choosing` is any 3-tuple whose values range from 0 to 255.

Your current 'main' function could look like:
`clear_color = (0,0,0)`
`while run:`
    `WIN.screen.fill((clear_color))`
    `WIN.blit(BG, (0,0))`
    `Raiden_start_pos = (r_x,r_y)`
    `WIN.blit(Raiden,(Raiden_start_pos))`
    `pygame.display.update()`
    `...`

Comment: It works now, thanks to you both!